# Is Java's Exception class a checked type?

Tags: java

Here is an example that shows contrary behavior of Java 'Exception' class.

```
try {

}
catch(Exception ex) {

}
```

In case of checked type of exception, if we keep a catch block without any error provoking statement to that particular checked exception in try block then, compiler will raise an error like “This exception is never thrown from the try statement body”. But in above case compiler will not give any error.

On the other hand, if we raise an exception of type 'Exception' class by using throw key word, the exception will not be automatically ducked to a caller, like below:

```
throw new Exception();
```

In above case compiler gives error like "`Unhandled exception type Exception`".

So is Java's Exception class a checked or unchecked type?

Comment: FYI, sub class of Throwable are checked and sub-clasess of RuntimeException and Error are not. You can sub-class Throwable and not have an Error or Exception.

Answer (score 14):

`Exception` *is* a checked exception. From [section 11.2 of the JLS](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/exceptions.html#44121):

> The unchecked exceptions classes are the class RuntimeException and its subclasses, and the class Error and its subclasses. All other exception classes are checked exception classes.

However, the behaviour you're seeing around being able to catch it without anything in the try block which is declared to throw anything is due to [section 14.20 of the JLS](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/statements.html#14.20):

> It is a compile-time error if a catch clause catches checked exception type E1 but there exists no checked exception type E2 such that all of the following hold:
>
> - E2 <: E1
> - The try block corresponding to the catch clause can throw E2
> - No preceding catch block of the immediately enclosing try statement catches E2 or a supertype of E2.
>
> unless E1 is the class Exception.

The reason for this is `RuntimeException`, which is an unchecked exception *subclass of `Exception`*. So unlike all other checked exceptions, it's possible for `catch (Exception)` to catch an unchecked exception, which can be viewed (in a simplified model) as being potentially thrown by *any* `try` block. Basically `RuntimeException` messes with the exception hierarchy :(

Answer (score 5):

Stuff you should know about Exceptions:

- `Exceptions` are *checked*, which means if declared as `throws`, they must be handled (caught). Roughly, these are for "non-programming errors". eg `IOException`
- `RuntimeExceptions` (a subclass of `Exception`) are *unchecked*, which means they do not need to be handled if declared, and may be thrown when not declared. Roughly, these are for "programming errors". eg `NullPointerException`
- `Errors` are unchecked, but are not `Exceptions` (see below). These are for "unrecoverable" errors. eg `OutOfMemoryError`
- `Throwable` is the abstract parent class of all of the above

Try this:

```
try {
    ....
} catch (RuntimeException e) {
    ....
}
```

or if you are expecting both runtime and non-runtime exceptions:

```
try {
    ....
} catch (Throwable e) {
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 2):

RuntimeException, Error, and their subclasses are unchecked exceptions. Rest all including super-classes are checked. Naturally as checked exceptions can be sub class of Exception, it itself has to be checked.

Answer (score 2):

**Checked Exception** The exception that are checked by the java compiler for smooth execution of the programme at runtime are called Checked Exception.

1. **Fully Checked Exception** Checked Exception is set to be fully checked if and only if all its child classes are checked.for e.g. IOException, InterruptedException etc.
2. **Partially Checked Exception** A Checked Exception is set to be partially checked if and only if some of its child classes are unchecked.
   In entire exception hierarchy the only partially checked exception are **Exception** and **Throwable**

**Unchecked Exception** The exception that are not raised by java compiler whether exception raises or not are called Unchecked Exception.

**Note:** **Exception class is neither Checked nor Unchecked Exception. It is Partially Checked Exception.**

Answer (score 0):

Jon Skeet was close but didn't get it exactly...he didn't explain the `throw` statement.  Your answer to that lies in section [14.18 - The `throw` Statement](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/statements.html#14.18) of the Java Language Specification, specifically:

> The Expression in a throw statement must denote a variable or value of
>   a reference type which is assignable (§5.2) to the type Throwable, or
>   a compile-time error occurs. Moreover, at least one of the following
>   three conditions must be true, or a compile-time error occurs:
>
> - The exception is not a checked exception (§11.2)-specifically, one of
>     the following situations is true:
>
>   - The type of the Expression is the
>       class RuntimeException or a subclass of RuntimeException.
>   - The type of
>       the Expression is the class Error or a subclass of Error.
> - The throw
>     statement is contained in the try block of a try statement (§14.20)
>     and the type of the Expression is assignable (§5.2) to the type of the
>     parameter of at least one catch clause of the try statement. (In this
>     case we say the thrown value is caught by the try statement.)
> - The
>     throw statement is contained in a method or constructor declaration
>     and the type of the Expression is assignable (§5.2) to at least one
>     type listed in the throws clause (§8.4.6, §8.8.5) of the declaration.

You are throwing an `Exception`, which is not a `RuntimeException` or sublcass of `RuntimeException`.  None of the other conditions apply either.

To verify this, throw a `new RuntimeException()` and see if the compiler complains.