# Is Exception class a checked or unchecked exception?

Tags: java, exception

Java [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-11.html) say that all subclasses of `Throwable`, other than `RuntimeException` and `Error`,  are *checked* exceptions. This also includes `java.lang.Exception` class which is direct child of `java.lang.Throwable`.

> The unchecked exception classes are the run-time exception classes and the error classes.
>
> The checked exception classes are all exception classes other than the unchecked exception classes. That is, the checked exception classes are all subclasses of Throwable other than RuntimeException and its subclasses and Error and its subclasses.

Catching a checked exception which is not thrown in try block give compile error only for subclasses of `Exception`, not for `Exception` itself. Why is that?

Does it mean that `java.lang.Exception` is *unchecked*?

```
public class CheckedExceptionTest {
    public static void good(){ System.out.println("I am good"); }

    public static void main(String []args){
        try {
            good();
        } catch (java.io.IOException e) { 
            // Compile error
            // exception IOException is never thrown in body of corresponding try statement
        }
    }
}
```

While this compiles and runs fine.

```
public class CheckedExceptionTest {
    public static void good(){ System.out.println("I am good"); }

    public static void main(String []args){
        try {
            good();
        } catch (java.lang.Exception e) { 
            // No compile error
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8426366/is-java-exception-class-checked-type

Comment: @Arty - Good find!

Comment: @Arty Google and SO search didn't help. Thanks for linking.

Comment: Although I'm not sure the duplicate addresses your question *"Catching a checked exception which is not thrown in try block give compile error only for subclasses of `Exception`, not for `Exception` itself. Why is that?"* (Nor does my now-deleted answer.)

Comment: seen this same question some weeks ago... searching - and found!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes, I am unable to understand what Jon Skeet is explaining there. One guy says its neither checked or unchecked but docs say otherwise.

Comment: see the [second duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52041230/85421) - it is more specific to the question  IMHO

Comment: Welldone downvoters, Thomas gave much better answer than all those marked as duplicate.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder T+Tab did that

Comment: well Thomas' answer may be better  - got my upvote -  (still I prefer the other one, more precise and concise) but that does not make the question unique (or better) - agreed the question does not deserve a downvote (just my opinion) and it still has one upvote

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any checked exception has to be declared or caught, thus the compiler knows which checked exceptions some piece of code can throw.

If a method only throws the checked exception `MySpecialException` then you only *have* to catch this, if it would declare `throws Exception` then you'd have to catch `Exception`.

However, using a generic `throws Exception` or `catch(Exception e)` is rarely a good idea and thus you should be using more specific exceptions anyway.

On the other hand since the compiler knows which checked exceptions can be thrown inside a try-block it is able to tell you about catch-blocks that *never* will be executed. That's not true for unchecked exceptions though.

So why does the compiler complain about `catch(IOException)` but not about `catch(Exception)`? That's because `IOException` *always* is a checked exception and hence the compiler knows it can't be thrown. `Exception` *could* also mean a `RuntimeException` and thus `catch(Exception)` would catch those as well, if there are any.

`Exception` itself is handled differently depending on where it's used:

- `throws Exception` or `throw new Exception(...)` tell the compiler that a *checked* exception has to be handled
- `catch(Exception)` tells the compiler that *any* exception, i.e. checked *or* unchecked should be handled and because of the unchecked part the compiler can't complain.

Note that the compiler will treat `throws Exception` differently than e.g. `throws IOException` for the same reasons:

- If you declare a special checked exception to be thrown in a method but it doesn't happen then the compiler is able to warn you about that (it's normally only a warning because the throws-clause could be dictated by some interface or superclass).
- If you declare `throws Exception` then it will handle the method as if it would throw checked exceptions only (i.e. you have to catch them) but since this *could* comprise `RuntimeException`s as well it can't warn you about exceptions not being thrown.

Comment: "since the compiler knows which checked exceptions can be thrown inside a try-block it is able to tell you about catch-blocks that never will be executed." but this does not work for Exception itself

Comment: @T.J.Crowder you're right, I'll add that

Comment: @SMUsamaShah that's not exactly true: if a block calls a method that declares `throws Exception` or directly throws `Exception` itself then the compiler will treat that as a checked exception and thus "knows" that _some_ form of a checked exception _could_ be thrown (I'll add a part on that "could").

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Ah! Now I understand. Just checked, it doesn't give error for `Throwable` either because it can also cater unchecked exceptions. That's a nice explanation.

Comment: Thanks @Thomas, that makes sense -- it's a consequence of that weird hierarchy. :-)